# Intersection of a non-empty set of natural numbers (set-theoretic definition) is a natural number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

This question is very similar to [Intersection of a non-empty set of natural numbers (set-theoretic definition) gives an element of that set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895955/intersection-of-a-non-empty-set-of-natural-numbers-set-theoretic-definition-gi)

Consider the following set-theoretic definition of natural numbers:

- $0$ is defined as $\emptyset$
- If $n$ is defined, then the successor of $n$ is defined as $n^+ = \{n\} \cup n$

Thus $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{0, 1\}$, and so on.

Let $\omega$ be the set of all natural numbers defined as above, and let $E$ be an arbitrary non-empty subset of $\omega$.

> How can we show that that the intersection of $E$ is a natural number?

Comment: I'm sure you noticed that the "natural numbers" so constructed (the finite von Neumann ordinals) are ordered by inclusion, i.e. nested.  So a smallest entry of $E$ would become the intersection over $E$.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use this to prove that E has a smallest entry in the first place, so I can't just say "take the smallest entry of E".

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't really presented the full "set-theoretic" definition of "natural numbers", so it's guesswork at this point to say how you would get a handle on finiteness.  One approach would be to use nonemptiness of $E$ and pick an element in it, say $n$.  Then $n$ should be finite, and $n$ should contain the intersection over $E$.  Since there are only finitely many "natural numbers" less than $n$, the intersection of $E$ and $n$ must be finite.  The finite sets are well-ordered, so the least element of $E$ must be one of them.

Comment: Your definition of $\omega$ is not exactly correct. Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the natural number in our universe (the one everyone is familiar with). For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, in any set theoretical universe, there exists the set $\hat{n}$ as you defined above. You suggest to define $\omega = \{\hat{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. However using the usual set theory axiom, you can not define a set this way since $\mathbb{N}$ is what you think of the natural number in our universe. In fact, by a compactness argument, there is a set theoretic universe where $\omega$ does not look like $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Therefore, the usual definition of the natural numbers is the least limit ordinal. Ordinal by definition are well-ordered sets under $\in$. Hence any $E \subseteq \omega$ has a least element.

Comment: Some texts define the set of natural numbers simply as [the smallest inductive sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22smallest+inductive+set%22), which is quite similar to what is written in the post.

Comment: Martin, this is indeed how the natural numbers are defined in the text I'm referencing (Halmos - Naive Set Theory).

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that this question was asked sometime in the past two weeks.

Comment: Asaf, does math.stackexchange.com have a prediction market for estimates like this (e.g. one where you can wager reputation points)? :)

Comment: BTW I think it would be helpful to mention also in your post(s) which book you are following. (The post still has to be self-contained, but if someone wants to see more detail, they know where to look.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be $\bigcap E$.  All elements of $E$ are natural numbers and thus all elements of $E$ are sets of natural numbers.  So, $x$ is a set of natural numbers.

As $E$ is not empty, there's a natural number $n_0 \in E$.  Clearly, $x \subseteq n_0$.

If $y \in x$, then $y \in n$ for all $n \in E$.  As all $n \in E$ are transitive, we have $y \subseteq n$ for all $n \in E$, so $y \subseteq \bigcap E = x$, i.e. $x$ is transitive.

Now you have that $x$ is a transitive set of natural numbers which is a subset of some natural number $n_0$.  Does that suffice?

Comment: I feel like this should suffice, but I still need to convince myself that "a transitive set of natural numbers which is a subset of some natural number is itself a natural number".

Comment: Yup, this suffices.  Let $S$ be the set of natural numbers for which every transitive subset is a natural number.  $0 \in S$ since the only possible subset of $0$ is just $0$.  Suppose $n \in S$, and let $x$ be a transitive subset of $n^+$.  If $n$ is not an element of $x$, then $x \subset n$, and we just use the inductive hypothesis.  Otherwise, $n \in x$, and transitivity implies $n \subset x$, so in fact $n^+ \subset x$, and $n^+ = x$.  Either way, $x$ is a natural number, and the proof is complete.

Comment: @Elliott Finally I can go to sleep (literally)! Just wondering, how can Halmos expect the reader to do this (the well-ordering principle exercise, which resulted in me looking for this question)!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As pointed out in Eliott's comment, the proof I have suggested is not correct:

> I feel like this should suffice, but I still need to convince myself that "a transitive set of natural numbers which is a subset of some natural number is itself a natural number"

However, he also suggests how the proof can be corrected:

> I ended up doing something like this: (1) prove by induction that if X is a non-empty subset of a natural number, then the intersection of X is a natural number; (2) find a set F such that the intersection of F is the same as the intersection of E, but F is a subset of a natural number.

---

We can prove by induction on $n$ that
$$a\in n \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad a\in\omega,$$
i.e., every element of a natural number is also a natural number.

We also [know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895955/intersection-of-a-non-empty-set-of-natural-numbers-set-theoretic-definition-gi#comment1849326_895955) for two natural number we have
$$m\in n \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad m\subsetneq n.$$

---

Now if you have $E\subseteq\omega$, $E\ne\emptyset$, and $a=\bigcap E$, then $a\subseteq n$ for each $n\in E$.

If there is an $n\in E$ such that $n\ne a$, we get $a\in n$. So by the above claim, $a$ is a natural number.

The other possibility is that $E=\{a\}$. In this case we have $a\in E\subseteq\omega$ which, clearly, means that $a\in\omega$.

Comment: This is repost of [my (now deleted) answer to the previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895955/intersection-of-a-non-empty-set-of-natural-numbers-set-theoretic-definition-gi/895968#895968). (I have misread that question and I have only discussed the proof that the intersection is a natural number, not that it belongs to the given set. So I have deleted my answer there, but I think it fits this question.)

Comment: Thanks Martin!  I agree that $a \subset n$ for each $n \in E$, but how did you then conclude that $a \in n$ for each $n \in E$?

Comment: @Elliott I have tried to correct my proof. Probably there is more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Martin, I'm still not fully convinced, since to me it looks like you're using the assumption that $a \in n$ if and only if $a$ is a proper subset of $n$ before you've proved that $a$ is a natural number.

Comment: That said, all this discussion has been immensely helpful anyway!  I ended up doing something like this: (1) prove by induction that if X is a non-empty subset of a natural number, then the intersection of X is a natural number; (2) find a set F such that the intersection of F is the same as the intersection of E, but F is a subset of a natural number